# How do I use text mail with using sendRestLink?

Tags: php, email, laravel

At First, please see this code.

```
$response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function (Message $message) {
      $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
  });
  switch ($response) {
      case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
          return redirect()->to('auth/password/sent')->with('status', trans($response));
      case Password::INVALID_USER:
          return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
  }
```

In this code, using password.blade.php as mail template.
but i want to use other mail template.
(Sorry, I dont't know why this code set password.blade.php as mail template.)

My question is "How to set other mail template in this code?"

Comment: Do you want to have two different mail templates? Why don't you edit the default one per your needs?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.   As you say, I want you two different mail template.  HTML mail and TEXT mail.  Do you know how to set two different mail template with sendResetLink?

Comment: what is the version?

Comment: Sorry,I forgot to say that. The version is 5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config/auth.php, find this section:

```
'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

For `email` you can actually set both html and text version of the password email. (html first!)

```
'passwords' => [
            'users' => [
                'provider' => 'users',
                'email' => ['emails.password.html', 'emails.password.text'],
                'table' => 'password_resets',
                'expire' => 60,
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It was great help !

Comment: Glad it was helpful!